# How do I convert from the string representation of a class to an instance of the class?

Tags: java, android

I have a string representation of a class's path. It could be any of three classes, all of which implement the same interface, **Adapter**, but I don't know what the value is.

- "com.example.adapters.Music"
- "com.example.adapters.Video"
- "com.example.adapters.Photo"

Given only a variable holding one of the three strings above, how can I get a usable instance of the actual class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
String name = "com.example.adapters.Music";
Object obj = Class.forName(name).newInstance();
```

You will then have to cast `obj` to the correct type (possibly by examining the name or by using `instanceof`). It is easier if your classes have a common base class (or interface that they implement) and you can use `obj` knowing only that it is some subclass.

This will only work if the class has a default constructor. Otherwise you will have to use reflection to get an instance of a constructor method and invoke it with the proper arguments.

Comment: Luckily the OP mentions that all possible classes should implement an interface named _Adapter_, so you can just cast to Adapter (maybe after doing a quick test with _instanceof_ or the _Class.isInstance()_ method).

Comment: @jahroy - Yes, it seems that OP can safely cast to an `Adapter`. However, the second part of the caveat still stands: this will help only if it is enough to know that the object is an `Adapter`, and knowledge of the specific type of `Adapter` is not needed.

Answer (score 3):

If a class has a no-argument constructor, then creating an object from its package-qualified class name (for example, "java.lang.Integer") is usually done using these methods:

```
Class.forName
Class.newInstance


For e.g MusicClass mObj = Class.forName(<string name>).newInstance();
```

If arguments need to be passed to the constructor, then these alternatives may be used instead:

```
Class.getConstructor
Constructor.newInstance
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use String array for holding three string

```
String names[]= {"com.example.adapters.Music","com.example.adapters.Video","com.example.adapters.Photo"};
```

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't my question.